# How to expand my irrigation system

Tags: irrigation

I would like to add an additional zone to my 4 zone irrigation system. I wondering if I can just add another manifold to my current setup. Below is what it looks like. The problem I think I will run into is that this valve box doesn't have room for an additional manifold. Do I have enough PVC to cut and add an additional zone? I do have a spare power wire for an additional zone.

[image]

Comment: to me, the picture doesn't show the whole box. And a ruler to show how much actual space is remaining might be helpful to anyone looking to answer this.

Comment: The spare wire is going to help a lot.  You can always find a way to add a valve, but doing a home run of another wire can be a big hassle.

Comment: Oh, just a note - the individual black devices are "valves".  When you talk about a "manifold", you're talking about a collection of valves.  Everything in this box together is the "manifold".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to refer to the valve at the top of your picture, but the same would apply to the bottom.  Between the last tee and the final ell, there is enough pipe to cut off the ell and glue on a coupling.  However, there is not enough room to glue on a coupling and a new tee to leave the top valve in its current position.  That top valve is going to have to move.  That would be a lot of trouble.

Instead, I think you should dig to the right of the picture and tap into the main line coming in to this current box.  There is bound to be a straight section of pipe that you can tee off of using a few unions or a repair coupling.  Once you tee off that main line, you can place a new valve in a smaller box wherever it's convenient.  Running your spare wire to the new box should be pretty easy as well.

Comment: I totally agree. Squeezing another valve in there looks as though it's going to require redoing the entire manifold, then you will not have your outgoing pipes line up. Too much trouble, not worth it. Tap in further up.

Comment: Is this what you're recommending. Sorry, I did this quickly I know drawing looks awful. https://i.ibb.co/6HwSx8h/Untitled.png

Comment: @Sam Assuming that circle outside the green box is the new valve then yes.  When you actually do this, you can of course space the new valve out a little.  Give your self room to work (I know its just a drawing).